# Mule ESB - NetSuite Integration for a file based interface?

Tags: mule, netsuite, mule-studio

I have a situation where in need to integrate a system which creates general ledger files with NetSuite. 
The "Source" System basically dumps the General Ledger feed in a file at a defined location and i am able to transform this file into the format that NetSuite expects. 
I read that Mule ESB can communicate with NetSuite either through the NetSuite Cloud connector or a web service channel. 
So far i am mapping the file content to a web-service ("Add-List" operation) and i am also aware of the Cloud Connector for NetSuite that Mule provides. 
Apart from these two i.e. web-service channel and NetSuite cloud connector, is there any other mechanism using which Mule can communicate with Netsuite? Does netsuite expose any API that would help me export batch requests in CSVs or any other file format?

Answer (score 1):

Netsuite does support CSV Import/Export. There are several options listed.

From NS Navigation menu go to Setup -> Import/Export

Comment: NetSuite does provide CSV import/export but that is through NetSuite's UI which again will require "manual" upload of CSVs. What i require is an exposed API which would help automate my process.

Comment: for that you have to use webservices

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can download the NetSuite user guide [HERE>](http://erpsolution-software.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-people-grow-businesses-with-netsuite.html)

If you need help, let me know. We even have an ex-NASA scientist on staff who now does **NetSuite Integrations.** And as you know, most of the old-school legacy desktop applications can be integrated.

[www.sererra.com](http://www.sererra.com)